# Should I create a read replica or scale the DB instance?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm using AWS's RDS PostgresQL DB

I recently traced an application error to the database connections being maxed out, I temporarily scaled the instance to support more connections since AWS's default behaviour is to use the instance's memory to calculate the maximum number of connections.

Most of the connections are due to clients reading data, so should I create a read replica instead of scaling the server? I'm thinking of this in terms of best practices, costs, and effort

Comment: Without knowing the real problem, why did you have so many open connections, it's impossible to give you some good advice.

Comment: @FrankHeikens we were using the smallest aws instance for our db server, and we recently started a lot of growth marketing campaigns

Comment: We serve almost 2 million customers daily with an average of 10 active database connections. That is more or less 80 million requests and hundreds of millions of (sub-) queries a day. Sometimes we go up to 11 or 12 active connections, but that's it. Every request is just lightning fast.

Answer (score 1):

It depends how much the IOPS are, if your app is read intensive and there are connections limitation as well. Read IOPS are directly related to EBS storage, if you are using general storage.

Thus if you are using general storage. First look at your Read IOPS, if they are on average higher than STORAGE_IN_GB*3 then go for a read replica.

Otherwise just connection issue should be fixed by scaling the instance up vertically.